# Conditions proof confusing

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

Given is `res[]`:

```
for(let k = 0; k < res.length; k++){
    if($("#getData").val().length == 20){

      //if ((res[k]) != $("#getData").val()) helpText = "No match!";
      // -- Tried this too and a several other options - foreach, else, else if e. g.
      if(!((res[k]) == $("#getData").val()))
        resText = "No match!";
      if((res[k]) == $("#getData").val())
        resText = "Success!";

    $("#result").html(resText);
    }
}
```

If the `!((res[k]) == $("#getData").val())` - "`false`" condition is defined, it always only makes the first `res[0]` item within the array valid. This item is possible to proof correctly - The array don´t iterate.

If the - "`false`" condition is **not** defined, all works fine if only the "`true`" condition is defined. But in this way there is no `resText == "No match!";`

What is wrong...?

Comment: Are you trying to end up with `resText === "Success!"` when *any* value in `res` is `$("#getData").val()`?

Comment: If the `false` condition is defined, `test ==="Success!"` returns `true` for `res[0]`, but it returns nothing for the other items.

Comment: If I comment the `false` condition out, `test ==="Success!"` returns true for `res[0]` and **all** the other items.

Comment: Since you overwrite the html every iteration of the loop.... the last iteration will be the only one that determines what is set

Comment: Sorry, I can´t see my fail. Please correct me - Less sleep, much programming. If you mean `$("#result").html(resText);` to put it after the loop, it´s done. But that not fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @charlietfl mentioned, you are looping across an array and updating the result text at each index. Because you are never stopping the looping process, what this really means is that you are only ever getting the result from the last item in the array. If your "Success!" value is item 14 in a 20 item array, your result will match and pass on that iteration, but then will be overwritten on the iterations for the next 5 items. If the very last item is a success condition you will always get "Success!" and if not you will always get "No match!" regardless of the other items in the list.

My assumption is that what you are looking to do is determine if one of the items in the array is a match, and if so you want "Success!" as the output. If so, I suggest:

```
const success = false;
const getDataVal = $("#getData").val();

if (getDataVal.length == 20) {
    for(let k = 0; k < res.length; k++) {
        if (res[k] == getDataVal) {
            success = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

$("#result").html(success ? "Success!" : "No match!");
```

I restructured your code a bit here to help me understand it. Note that I did some optimizations to it:

- Moved the $("#getData").val() operation out of the loop and stored to a variable since the value will not change. This simplifies the code and is much easier on the processor.
- Moved the condition on the length check of the value outside the loop. The loop contents would only ever run whenever that condition is true, so it is better to wrap the loop in the condition so that it never runs at all if that condition fails.
- Added a break; to the loop to stop the loop once a success condition is found
- Moved the setting of the #result outside the loop. This only needs to be done once you know the answer and not at every iteration.
- Use a ternary with a simple boolean instead of strings to know the status of the match and output the final string.

If my assumption is correct that you are really interested in knowing if *any* item in the array matches, then I suggest using the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method of the array to evaluate it. This is a bit more expressive and removes the need for the looping structure.

```
let success = false;
const getDataVal = $("#getData").val();

if (getDataVal.length == 20) {
    success = res.some(function (val)) {
        return val == getDataVal;
    });
}

$("#result").html(success ? "Success!" : "No match!");
```